# javascript - create unlimited new divs from text area value

Tags: javascript

I have a text area where users can submit posts, and I'm putting them in my database using ajax, but I want to create a new div below the text area when they hit submit, so that they know that it worked.

```
    var text = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
    // $.post( "../parsers/new_text.php", { text: text } );
    var area = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
    area.value = "";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(text);
    var elem = document.getElementById("texts");
    elem.appendChild(div);
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

This is what I have so far, and everything works up to `area.value="";` but it's not creating a new div inside a div I have below the text area whose ID is "texts". I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a text node with `createTextNode()` and add it to the `div` element, adding the plain `text` string won't work. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2L22/1/).